# In matlab, how to read python pickle file?

Tags: python, matlab

In python, I generated a .p data file by

```
pickle.dump( allData, open( "myallData.p", "wb" ))
```

Now I want to read myallData.p in Matlab. (My Matlab is installed under Windows 8, which does not have python in it.) Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ended up with read the data back from the .p file:

```
[whatever_data]=pickle.load( open( "myallData.p", "rb" ) )
```

Then use scipy to convert and save the data to .mat

```
import numpy, scipy.io
scipy.io.savemat('/home/myfiles/mydata.mat', mdict={'whatever_data': whatever_data})
```

So as to avoid dealing with pickle.

Answer (score 0):

matlab and python pickle do not use the same format. 
You can use this [writeup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/copying-external-data-into-mat-file-format-with-standalone-programs.html) to format the data in a way matlab can understand.