# How do we import a .pkl file in Matlab?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, neural-network, pickle, matlab-guide

I trained a neural model in python and saved it in my directory in pkl format.
I want to import this pkl file in Matlab. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In matlab, how to read python pickle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859968/in-matlab-how-to-read-python-pickle-file)

Comment: It seems to be best to use scipy for saving your data in .mat format. There are also some options for import keras modules from .h5 files using a plug-in